# Elasticsearch-Kibana docker-compose - Value of "elastic" is forbidden

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I want to run elasticsearch and kibana with docker-compose.
This is my docker-compose.yml which I run with docker-compose --env-file dev.env up

Docker Compose

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.1.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=elasticsearch-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enrollment.enabled=true
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - esnet
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.1.1
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local
  postgres-data:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Stacktrace

`Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].username]: value of "elastic" is forbidden. This is a superuser account that cannot write to system indices that Kibana needs to function. Use a service account token instead`

I manage to create service-account token for example for user elastic/kibana, but how can I set it to docker-compose? Is there a specific env variabile that should I use?
Or is there a way to make it work without the usage of service account?

Comment: Have you found out the solution. I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I used elasticsearch 7.15.2 and I solved this error. Currently, this is the last version supported by spring.

Comment: Use `kibana_system` user and create a password with `until curl -s -X POST -u "elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://es01:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"${KIBANA_PASSWORD}\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;` . You can find an example in the official docker compose doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-compose-file It is multi nodes, but you can only keep one to be single node.

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled upon the same issue and tried using the `kibana_admin` and `kibana_system` [built-in users](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-roles.html) but that didn't work either. Maybe you can set the password for these users but I was not able to.
The `elastic` user role is not allowed to have `system-index write-access` which Kibana needs. This is based on a change by Elastic ([Link to Pullrequest](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/81400)).

You should instead use Service Accounts as described in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.1/service-accounts.html) for Service Accounts.
Apparently, according to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-create-service-token.html) on creating a Service Account Token, you would have to somehow create the Elasticsearch container and create a token before starting the Kibana container.
This is also discussed on the Elasticsearch [forums](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-error-fatal-error-config-validation-of-elasticsearch-username-value-of-elastic-is-forbidden/297956/4).

Downgrading and using a previous ELK version is also a possibility and is what I did, since I only need the cluster for local development.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your service account token with this environment: "ELASTICSEARCH_SERVICEACCOUNTTOKEN" in your docker-compose. I managed to set service-account token for Kibana in my docker-compose like this:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
 Elasticsearch:
   image: elasticsearch:8.10.2
   container_name: elasticsearch
   restart: always
   volumes:
   - elastic_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
   environment:
     ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
     discovery.type: single-node
     ELASTIC_PASSWORD: elastic123
   ports:
   - '9200:9200'
   - '9300:9300'
   networks:
     - elk
 Logstash:
   image: logstash:8.10.2
   container_name: logstash
   restart: always
   volumes:
   - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro
   command: logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
   depends_on:
     - Elasticsearch
   ports:
   - '9600:9600'
   - '5044:5044'
   environment:
     LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
     ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: elastic
     ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: elastic123
     XPACK_MONITORING_ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: elastic
     XPACK_MONITORING_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: elastic123
     XPACK_MONITORING_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: "elasticsearch:9200"
     XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED: "true"
   networks:
     - elk

 Kibana:
   image: kibana:8.10.2
   container_name: kibana
   restart: always
   ports:
   - '5601:5601'
   environment:
     - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
     - ELASTICSEARCH_SERVICEACCOUNTTOKEN=MY_TOKEN
   depends_on:
     - Elasticsearch
   networks:
     - elk
volumes:
 elastic_data: {}
networks:
 elk:
```

My logstash.conf file:

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => "5044"
        type => syslog
        codec => json_lines
    }
}


output {
    stdout { # This will log all messages so that we can confirm that Logstash is receiving them
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
        index => "logstash"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "elastic123"
    }
}
```

Also I used this command to create the service-account token for kibana:

```
curl -X POST -u elastic:elastic123 "localhost:9200/_security/service/elastic/kibana/credential/token/token1?pretty"
```