# Cannot open kibana due to server username

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

every time I try to connect kibana, I get this error:

```
Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].username]: value of "elastic" is forbidden. This is a superuser account that cannot write to system indices that Kibana needs to function. Use a service account token instead. Learn more: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/service-accounts.html
```

The host is:

```
host: 35.240.189.5:9200
user: elastic
with a password (private)
```

What should I do? If I need to get a token, how can I get a token? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to add a comment yet so I am sorry for writing this as an answer.
Assuming you are using docker-compose, I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71937294/16907308).
Which would also qualify this question as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71615937/16907308)